# COSMIC C - How to add assembler file to C code

Tags: c, stm8

I am getting this error when using atomthreads in cosmic c for stm8L151c6 micro controller.

`clnk - symbol _archFirstThreadRestore not defined (Debug\atomkernel.o)`

Ifound out that _archFirstThreadRestore is defined inside a assembler file named `atomports_asm_cosmic.s` linker cannot find those routines in the assembler file. How can I make linker to add the assembler file to the c code where those functions are used.

Answer (score -1):

Yes got it.
I got it worked.
The problem was I have to add assembler files to the project source files. Which I didn't do.

Comment: Please answer in more details.